# Unknown class ZBarReaderView in Interface Builder file

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on the `ZBarReader` and getting an error

Unknown class `ZBarReaderView` in Interface Builder file

> [UIView setReaderDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6859f20

Please look at an attached image at [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEAzJ.png) or below so that you can picture what I am doing so far :-

[image]

In the storyboard, I do have a view and its custom class is `ZBarReadView`. I also wire it with `IBOutlet` in header file. In m file, I do

> viewReader.readerDelegate = self;

and the error is shown after right after that.

Can anybody please point out what I have screwed up....

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Trying to solve it right now...

Comment: I found a easier solution, you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819779/cant-see-iboutlets-when-using-storyboard-with-zbarreaderview/13037464#13037464

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found the solution in a [thread over here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/forums/forum/1072195/topic/4701140)

You need to add the following code in your `applicationDidLaunch` in your AppDelegate:

`// force view class to load so it may be referenced directly from NIB
[ZBarReaderView class];`

Should be running fine after that.

Comment: // force view class to load so it may be referenced directly from NIB [ZBarReaderView class];
it doesn't work for Xcode 4.4
any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can also try to download [64bits ZbarSDK](https://github.com/null09264/ZBarSDK-for-iOS).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you actually added a view in interface builder and tried to call it a `ZbarReaderView` for IB to hook up. Correct me if I'm wrong but in this instance I don't think Ib is going to know what you mean by `ZBarReaderView`.

I'm Also assuming you haven't actually implemented the delegate method in your .m file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution should be to add -ObjC flag to "Other Linker Flags" section in your Build Settings. If you can't do this, e.g. you are using Parse Framework that doesn't allow you to set this flag, you will probably have to use the provided solution of Morothat: Set in your AppDelegate the following:

```
[YOURCLASSNAME class];
```